# stringstream duplicates last word

Tags: c++

I'm trying to split a string using stringstream :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream fp;
    string name;

    fp.open("in.txt");
    while (fp){
        string line;
        getline(fp, line);
        cout << line << endl;
        istringstream line_stream(line);

        while (line_stream){
            line_stream >> name;
            cout << name << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's in.txt :

```
cat bat rat sat
```

Here's the output I'm getting :

```
cat bat rat sat
cat bat rat sat sat
```

The line retrieved from `getline()` function is right, but in the process of splitting I'm getting the last word twice. I'm not sure why is this happening.

Comment: The problem is `while (line_stream)`. Use `while (line_stream >> name) { ... }`

Comment: @gx_ wouldn't you add it as answer ?

Comment: @triclosan Because it's not a complete answer.  (And it doesn't explain _why_.)

Comment: @triclosan No it was just intended to be a quick hint (there was still no answer at the time and I didn't have time/motivation to write one) (James Kanze is right ;) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the results of `getline` without checking whether
it succeeded.  This is the first error (and probably results in
an extra empty line with the code you show).  Similarly, you use
the results of `line_stream >> name` without checking whether it
succeeded; in this case (because `name` is not newly constructed
each time through), you may end up with the previously read
value (but in both cases, the contents of the string are
unspecified).

You must *never* use the results of input without first testing
whether it succeeded.  The most common way of doing this (but
certainly not the only way) is to do the input in the condition
of the loop:

```
while ( std::getline( fp, line ) ) ...
```

and

```
while ( line_stream >> name ) ...
```

*If* you still want to limit the scope of the variable to the
loop, you'd have to write:

```
while ( fp ) {
    std::string line;
    if ( std::getline( fp, line ) ) {
        //  rest of loop
    }
}
```

If you have (understandably) something against modifying global
state in a condition, you'd have to write:

```
std::getline( fp, line );
while ( fp ) {
    //  ...
    std::getline( fp, line );
}
```

While I think that there are strong arguments in favor of this,
the `while ( std::getline( fp, line ) )` idiom is ubiquitous, to
the point where anything else will cause the reader to wonder
why.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying:

```
while (fp){
    string line;
    getline(fp, line);
    ...
```

You should say:

```
string line;
while(getline(fp, line)) { ...
```

This is because when fp gets into eof state, getline fails (and sets fp to eof state). You do not check the result of the getline so for the last step you use the previously read value.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with the Loop. Once it reads last word from file and again comes to loop, that condition doesn't fail and again it goes to loop.

Change both `while` loops to

```
while(getline(fp, line))
```

**&**

```
while (line_stream >> name)
```

This will prevent the repetition as in this condition, last `name` will not be processed twice. Currently when `fp` approaches `eof`, `getline` fails. `getline` is not checked and previously read value is used, without checking if it succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the suggested changes detecting the end of file by checking the result of `getline`, the same principle should apply to the `stringstream`, so:

```
while (line_stream){
```

should be:

```
while (line_stream >> name) {
```

That way, when there is "nothing left to make another name", you don't get the last `name` processed twice.

Comment: It works, but sadly I am still not able to understand why?, I mean when I do line_stream >> name, shouldn't line_stream become empty at the last word, and thus when it comes back to the loop, it is now False.

Comment: The `fail` bit of a stream (whether string, file or any other) is set when the last read failed. So if we have a stream that contains `Joe !` (where `!` indicates the end of data), then the `fail` will happen AFTER the name "Joe" has been read. But since the test (in the original code) happens before the space between the end of data and the name "Joe" has been read, the stream is not in a "failed" state yet. So you end up processing "Joe" twice - because the failing read doesn't alter `name`, but there's no check made to see if that succeeded.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Even without the extra space: the read of `"Joe"` succeeds.  It sets `eofbit`, but that doesn't mean failure, and testing the stream will still work.  It's only when he tries to read an additional word with `eofbit` set that input fails.